# r.sunmask.datetime QGIS GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to make a map using r.sunmask.datetime in QGIS GRASS. Now i have to following problem. The Netherlands is largely under sealevel, and I am starting to believe that files, which heights are below 0 are crashing.

What can be the reason of this constant crashing?

Remember, I also have parts of maps which are above sealevel which just work correctly.

Comment: What happens if you enable the `z` flag (_Do not ignore zero elevation_)?